# Google Maps Geocoding API returns undesired result after being passed zip code

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use the Google Maps Geocoding API. When I pass in the zip 75116, I get Paris, France. Specifically: 48.8585799, lon = 2.284701700000028. I should get Duncanville, Texas.

This is the URL I'm using:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&client=CLIENT-NAME&v=3.21

I tried appending this to the URL but it didn't work:

> &components=country:US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the maps-Javascript-API the [componentRestrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#GeocoderComponentRestrictions) must be passed along with the `geocoderRequest`

```js
function init() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0),
      zoom: 13
    }),
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
      address: '75116',
      componentRestrictions: {
        country: 'us'
      }
    },
    function(r, s) {
      if (s == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(r[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: r[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        window.alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + s);
      }
    }

  );

}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=init">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two locations in the response for the "75116" geocoding request: Paris and Duncanville. Apparently, "75116" is not a unique location identifier.
Requesting "US 75116" results in the single expectable location.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use geocoder for getting address using zipcode:

Here sample code is provided:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAtRkkKYEMY8CX1IbWbsAYLqzh-_pecegg&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
    <script>

    var map;
    function initMap() {
       var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.8585799, 2.284701700000028);
       var mapOptions = {
          center : myLatlng,
          zoom : 17
        };
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
      geocoder.geocode({
            address : '75116',
            componentRestrictions: {
              country: 'us'
            }
        }, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        } else {
          // alert("no asdsd");
        }
      });

    }
    </script>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```